# Unexpected Issue when Using defer-lite in combination with a Mutable Struct

Tags: rust, mutable

I'm quite new to Rust but I've run into a strange issue that is likely me misunderstanding how the defer-lite crate works.

If I have the below code then everything is working as expected

```
use defer_lite::defer;

fn main() {

    println!("Start");

    defer! {
        println!("Stop");
    }

    println!("Interval");

}
```

I get the output that I want as

```
Start
Interval
Stop
```

Then when I try to include a mutable struct

```
use defer_lite::defer;

struct Timer {
    start:i32, interval:i32, stop:i32
}

fn timer_initialize() -> Timer {
    let timer = Timer{start:0, interval:0, stop:0 };
    return timer;
}

impl Timer {
    fn timer_start(&mut self) { self.start = 1; }
    fn timer_interval(&mut self) { self.interval = 2; }
    fn timer_stop(&mut self) { self.stop = 3; }
}

fn main() {

    let mut timer = timer_initialize();

    println!("Start");
    timer.timer_start();

    defer! {
        println!("Stop");
        timer.timer_stop();
    }

    println!("Interval");
    // uncommenting this line will cause a compiler error
    //timer.timer_interval();

}
```

Everything still works fine until I try to use the struct methods below the `defer!` at which point I will get a compiler error

```
timer.timer_interval();
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
```

I'm not sure why this is and if I am using defer-lite wrong

Comment: Please add the full error message from `cargo check`. That being said, you probably need to wrap your `Timer` struct in a [`RefCell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.54.0/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a limitation of this crate. This cannot be implemented in Rust. The problem is that in order to do its work, `defer-lite` creates a RAII guard that holds the cleanup code as a closure. But the closure holds a mutable reference to the value, so you cannot use it again until it is dropped - at the end of the scope.

If you need that I'd recommend the [scopeguard](https://lib.rs/crates/scopeguard) crate which is also much more popular. It provides a [`guard()`](https://docs.rs/scopeguard/latest/scopeguard/fn.guard.html) function for this case. It works like:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut timer = timer_initialize();

    println!("Start");
    timer.timer_start();

    let mut timer = scopeguard::guard(timer, |mut timer| {
        println!("Stop");
        timer.timer_stop();
    });

    println!("Interval");

    timer.timer_interval();
}
```

Comment: Wow, that is a huge relief sort of, moving over to scopeguard was exactly what I needed